# linq: what is the expression tree syntax for cross join

Tags: linq, expression-trees

how to write this linq query in expression tree syntax

```
from x in 100.To(999)
from y in 100.To(999)
let product = x * y
where product.IsEven()
select product
```

Comment: the cartesian product of two collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to the 'from x from y select' is the 'SelectMany' keyword used with an additional 'Select':

```
100.To(999).SelectMany(x => 100.To(999).Select(y => x * y))
.Where(x => x.IsEven())
```